# Does the word "mi" mean anything by itself in finnish?

Tags: etymology, finnish

Starting to learn finnish, I have noticed lots of question words in finnish all start with the syllable "mi": mika, mista, missa, miten ...

Does "mi" mean anything by itself, or is there a reason why so many question words start this way?

Comment: It’s archaic, but it’s [an old form of the relative pronoun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mi#Finnish) (now _mikä_ like the interrogative). The _-kä_ in _mikä_ [is a later extension](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mikä#Finnish), perhaps to avoid the word being monosyllabic.